# What is the difference between (var1 !== var2) vs (var1 && var1 !== var2) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `(var1 !== var2)` vs `(var1 && var1 !== var2)` in JavaScript?

The above question is in reference to when working with HTMLElementObjects as variables.

Google Chrome's extension development example shows this in the below function:

```
  let current = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(
    `.${selectedClassName}`
  );
  if (current && current !== event.target) {
    current.classList.remove(selectedClassName);
  }

  let color = event.target.dataset.color;
  event.target.classList.add(selectedClassName);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ color });
}
```

Why does it have to be "current && current"? It doesn't work with just "current !== event.target"

Link to full article for reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#logic

Comment: Think of it as `(current) && (current !== event.target)`

Comment: in javascript you have the concept of a "truthy" or "falsey" value. It could be an indication that you only want to enter the if statement if current is not a value like `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Read it as "Do I Exist" AND "Do I not equal this", When you remove the first check, it is "Do I not equal this" which is true. You than do in and try to access something that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of JavaScript's [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> 11: Strict Inequality (`!==`)
> ...
> 7: Logical AND (`&&`)

Since strict inequality has a higher precedence than logical AND, it's functionally equivalent to the following:

```js
(current) && (current !== event.target)
```

The people who wrote the tutorial likely did not want this expression to evaluate as true if `current` was any kind of falsey value. By doing this, they ensure that `event.target` can't just be any old value and still pass.

Answer (score 1):

What it does is checks if current is truthy *AND* is not equal to event.target. If event.target and current are both null it will still return false

Comment: `event.target` can't be `null` (the prior line would throw an exception if so), so the case described in your second sentence is impossible. The goal is to verify `current` is *something* (not `null` or whatever), *and* that it's not the same as `event.target`. The controlled block is intended to execute only when `current` is a new "something" that is not the same as `event.target`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It was just an example, I know.

Answer (score -1):

The first Var checking in `var && var...` is checking if var is not null or undefined and then compare It with var2
In fact, you could write It like that :

```
If (var !== null || var !== undefined || var !== false) {
 return  var !== var2
}
```